# UIDatePicker's wheel is not displayed correctly while scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker's wheel is not displayed correctly while scrolling. This problem occurs if I hide UIDatePicker Controller or navigate in another screen.

[image]

Comment: does this behaviour appear when you scroll or when the datapicker just opens?

Comment: Do u wanna either current date or you wanna reload your picker view.

Comment: when i m scrolling datepicker's wheel.and i just hide a date picker controller at a time.

Comment: Couldn't get you.. Can you please explain a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two way 
1. Using gesture recogniser.
2.You can add target like this ..

First add target in viewDidLoad.

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)valueChanged
{
   // --- you can hide your picker view here 
   [datePicker setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, try setting the date, it looks as if the animation was halted, this should reset the location:

```
[picker setDate:[picker date] animated:NO];
```